# How can I know whether a JobScheduler is running?

Tags: android

After I invoke Code A, the `JobScheduler` will keep running even if I close the APP.

But some customize Android system maybe clear `JobScheduler` when close the APP.

How can check if the `JobScheduler` is running programmatically?

**Code A**

```
private fun startScheduleRestore(mContext:Context){
   logError("Start Server")

   val interval=if (isDebug())
                    10*1000L
                 else
                    mContext.getInteger(R.integer.AutoRestoreInterval)*60*1000L

    val mJobScheduler = mContext.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE) as JobScheduler

    val jobInfo = JobInfo.Builder(mContext.getInteger(R.integer.JobID), ComponentName(mContext, RestoreService::class.java))
                        .setPeriodic(interval)
                        .setPersisted(true)
                        .build()

    mJobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo)
}
```

**Code B**

```
private fun stopScheduleRestore(mContext:Context){
    logError("Stop Server")

    val mJobScheduler = mContext.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE) as JobScheduler
    mJobScheduler.cancel(mContext.getInteger(R.integer.JobID))

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `getAllPendingJobs` method of JobScheduler. Based on [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html#getAllPendingJobs()):

> a list of all of the app's scheduled jobs. This includes jobs that are
>   currently started as well as those that are still waiting to run.

```
public static boolean isJobSchedulerRunning(final Context context) {
    final JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) context.getSystemService( Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE );    
    return jobScheduler.getAllPendingJobs().size() > 0;
}
```

**If want to check if particular JobId is still valid then you can do following:**

```
public static boolean isJobIdRunning( Context context, int JobId) {
    final JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) context.getSystemService( Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE ) ;

    for ( JobInfo jobInfo : jobScheduler.getAllPendingJobs() ) {
        if ( jobInfo.getId() == JobId ) {
           return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: what do mean by "check if particular JobId is still valid"? Do you mean that It is not started yet or it is actually running(onStartJob has been called)? And what happens if its a periodic job. DO I always get true from this method?

Answer (score 3):

Run Adb Command

```
adb shell dumpsys jobscheduler
```

It will show you list of jobs scheduled and you can identify you own task

Comment: Thanks! but it's not programmatically way

Answer (score 1):

Since you know your job ID, you can directly check whether the job is scheduled:

```
JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) context.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
boolean isScheduled = jobScheduler.getPendingJob(JOB_ID) != null;
if (isScheduled) {
    // Your job is scheduled!
}
```

This method will only work from API level 24. See [getPendingJob(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html#getPendingJob(int)) for more info.